# Where did the phrases "God the Son" and "God the Holy Spirit" came from?

Tags: trinity

1. We find the term "God the father" in the new testament. But we don't find "God the Son" nor "God the Holy Spirit."
2. There is no part which talks about the Son and the Holy Spirit in the old testament.

Can we say it is because Jesus wasn't born that the Son wasn't referred in the old testament?  If so, then what about the Holy Spirit?

Comment: I recommend that you use our search bar, put in the tag [trinity] and review some of the questions on Christology and the Nature of God that have already been answered.  Pretty sure this question has already been answered.  There are loads of questions about the trinity already.

Comment: Here is a good place to start: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/what-is-the-earliest-use-of-the-phrase-god-the-son/47890#47890

Comment: In Genesis there is the Spirit of God hovering over the waters